# DropDownList duplicates after setting DataTextField to string in XML

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

I am Reading an XML into a data set in C# and then I am populating a `DropDownList` with id numbers found in items in the XML, like this:

```
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
dataSet.ReadXml(myPathToXML);
```

Then populating:

```
idDropDownList.DataSource = dataSet;
idDropDownList.DataTextField = "id";
idDropDownList.DataBind();
```

However, this seems to create duplicates in my `DropDownList` which I don't want.

EDIT:

Would it be possible to have the last item in the dropdown as something like "New ID" and when the user selects that, the dropdown is replaced by a `TextBox` where he/she can enter a new (unique) ID?

Comment: Your edit is asking a completely new question. . . and for your first question what have you tried to solve your problem? First thing off top of my head are to filter the xml results yourself using a linq distinc query.

Comment: @CodyG. you are right, my edit adds another question. I am sorry for making that mistake! I will try to make a new edit and clarify what I have tried so far related to the first question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first part of your question, 
do `idDropDownList.Clear()` before `DataBind()`

For the second - there are many options
For example:
1. Append one more row to DataSet before Databind();
2. have a hidden TextBox
3. Handle SelectedIndexChanged event: hide DropDownList and show TextBox
4. Handle LostFocus event of TextBox, perform databind and switch visibility of controls back.

Comment: Thank you, this is enough to lead me into the right direction!